# setRadius on Circle gives bad user experience in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to implement something like in `Google Maps` samples and their `CircleDemoActivity`:

[Android Samples](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/CircleDemoActivity.java)

The problem is that, the circle is disappearing and appearing, and I recorded that problem

[Google Maps Sample problem](https://youtu.be/W_JIRVz_n3U)

In my opinion that part should work:

```
if (marker.equals(radiusMarker)) {
    radius = toRadiusMeters(centerMarker.getPosition(), radiusMarker.getPosition());
    circle.setRadius(radius);
    return true;
}
```

and the problem is with `setRadius` method, but maybe is some workaround.

**Question**

How to fix that?

Comment: This is [a known bug in Google Maps](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5707).

Comment: Do you know any workaround ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't, but an interesting idea is described in [that thread](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5707#c14).

Comment: Seems issue fixed [Oct 24, 2016](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5707#c24)

Answer (score 1):

Few months ago I had to implement an animation of a circle growing and shrinking to under a marker to inform our user that the marker location was not precisely known.

In a first implementation I used a circle and had the same issue.
I ended up using a [GroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay) with a circle image and it does not blink. It may just require more maths to get the correct radius.

I hope it could help :)

Comment: I had the same problem, and ended up with the same solution. There's just no other way to do it right now.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to use a [GroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay) instead of a circle.
Here's a sample :

```
// The drawable to use for the circle
    GradientDrawable d = new GradientDrawable();
    d.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
    d.setSize(500,500);
    d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    d.setStroke(10, Color.BLACK);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getIntrinsicWidth()
            , d.getIntrinsicHeight()
            , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    // Convert the drawable to bitmap
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    d.draw(canvas);

    // Maximum radius of the circle
    final int radius = 1000;

    // Add the circle to the map
    final GroundOverlay circle = map.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
    .position(latLng, 2 * radius).image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)));
```

Now in your code :

```
if (marker.equals(radiusMarker)) {
radius = toRadiusMeters(centerMarker.getPosition(), radiusMarker.getPosition());
circle.setDimensions(2 * radius);
return true;
```

}